# How can i toggle the sliver appbar to activate or deactivate itself and act as a normal appbar?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have 2 tabs in my app, can i toggle the sliver appbar to act like a normal appbar when im on the second tab but remain flexible on the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the sample code not much help could be provided.
At the very least a GitHub link to the repo.

However based on your question you could look into state management.
whereby there is conditional rendering of widget.
The page will render a normal app bar in one state and the other state render the flexible app bar.

Comment: ooo why i didnt thought about it, thanks for the tip.